# Moving div floated left to bottom of layout

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hi I have the  layout shown below, and in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7X4RQ/3/)

```
#divHeader#divHeader#divHeader

#divleftmenu #divContent
#divleftmenu #divContent
#divleftmenu #divContent
#divleftmenu #divContent

#divFooter#divFooter#divFooter
```

Is there a way using media queries and CSS only to move the the `#divleftmenu` to the bottom above the footer?

ie

```
 #divHeader#divHeader#divHeader

 #divContent
 #divContent
 #divContent
 #divContent

 #divleftmenu 
 #divleftmenu 
 #divleftmenu 
 #divleftmenu 


 #divFooter#divFooter
```

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle? We can't really understand how your code is laid out from your id's

Comment: Yea, create a fiddle. if you don't know already, the link is http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OKay will provide fiddle

Comment: Added fiddle to top, thanks guys

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use absolute positioning, though this is not my favourite method since it creates a very inflexible design: http://jsfiddle.net/7X4RQ/5/

Comment: I was afraid you where going to use absolute, i need this happen in the media query, not on the initial styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your source order, and stop floating your sidebar under your breakpoint. Just to be nice, I reformatted your code for you. I have:

- Removed unnecessary declarations
- Used more descriptive selector names
- Cleaned whitespace

[Here's your cleaner version](http://jsfiddle.net/7X4RQ/9/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>A much nicer version.</title>
<style type="text/css">
#header {height: 50px; background: yellow;}
#sidebar {float: left; height: 300px; width: 30%; background:blue;}
#content {float: right; height: 300px; width: 70%; background: #ccc;}
#footer {height: 50px; background: grey; clear:both;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #sidebar, #content {float: none; width: 100%;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: Thanks but this will not get div#right above div#left. Whoops just re-read about layout hangon will try it

Comment: @davey, you'll just need to style the `#right` differently initially... add `float: right;` for instance, or something of the kind

Comment: This means I have to float my content to the right to get it to worl.